# Проблема с файлом политики между AS3 и сервером Java

Tags: java, сокет, actionscript-3

Когда пытаюсь подключиться к серверу java - в ответ приходит policy-file-request.
собственно, когда передаю этот файл - результата ноль.

Вот код подключение в самом клиенте as3

```
socket = new Socket(param1,param2);
socket.connect(param1,param2);
socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA,sd);
socket.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE,sc);
socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, connectHandler);
socket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,sc);
```

Comment: Кросс доменные политики(cross-domain-policy) для сервера установлены?

Comment: Запрос policy файла происходит по одному порту, (вроде 801), и ваш код в нем не участвует (это делает флеш плеер), обмен данным по другому (любому, у вас param2) который в настройках java socket server.

Comment: т.е. мне надо по отдельному сокету, с портом 801 передавать клиенту тот файл?